# Positive determinant of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If the determinant of the hermitian part of a matrix $A$ is positive, can I say that $\det A$ is positive too? If so, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a counterexample is 
$$A = \pmatrix{-2 & -4 & -2 \\ 2 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & -4 & -5}$$
whose determinant is $-36$ but whose symmetric part, $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T),$ has determinant $\frac{49}{2}$.

Comment: @RobertoDias No problem! If you feel that this answers your question, you can "accept" my answer by clicking on the little checkmark found to the left of my answer. Read more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).